# display only 1 column from the subquery : list the bran_name whos avg price is >= 3 and also have at least 2 distinct products

Tags: sql, count, azure-sql-database, aggregate-functions, having-clause

Here is my query:

```
select avg(p2.price), p2.brand_name, count(distinct p2.product_id) 
count_of_products
from product p2
group by p2.brand_name
having count(distinct p2.product_id) >= 2 and avg(p2.price) > 3
```

but I need to display only `band_name` in the final query.
I tried this:

```
select p1.brand_name from product p1,
(select avg(p2.price), p2.brand_name, count(distinct p2.product_id) 
count_of_products
from product p2
group by p2.brand_name
having count(distinct p2.product_id) >= 2 ) p2 and and avg(p2.price) > 3
where 
p1.brand_name = p2.brand_name
```

but it gives me following error:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 3-9 --------------------------
 No column name was specified for column 1 of 'p2'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I need to display only band_name in the final query

So just remove the other columns from the `select` clause:

```
select brand_name
from product
group by brand_name
having count(distinct product_id) >= 2 and avg(price) > 3
```

Comment: updated my question: I need only those brands whos avg(price) is > 3 @GMB

Comment: @gabs: you can add that condition to the `having` clause.